# Beginner Code Problem : "Sub or Function not Defined"

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm new in the VBA world and I'm currently trying to create a function.

I'm creating a planning in excel for a personal project.

I have 4 differents type of Start Dates.

1. Type 1: the date is the earliest date of a groupe of date
2. Type 2: the date is fully manual and is filled by the user and therefore the function return ""
3. Type 3: the date is coming from another worksheet in the same workbook
4. Type 4: the date is linked to another date of the planning

As you can imagine it's not working...because apparently the function is not defined...

If you could help me solve this that could be great.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function StartDate(dateType As Range, _
                          Optional stateTask As Range, _
                          Optional groupeDate As Range, _
                          Optional dateSimp As Range, _
                          Optional dateLink As Range, _
                          Optional dateSpacing As Range)

Application.Volatile

If Worksheet("TIME-DATE PARAM").Range("dateType").Value = 1 Then

    If Worksheet("TIME-DATE PARAM").Range("stateTask") <> 0 Then

        StartDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min("groupeDate")

    Else

        StartDate = ""

    End If

Else: Worksheet("TIME-DATE PARAM").Range("dateType").Value = 2

    StartDate = ""

Else: Worksheet("TIME-DATE PARAM").Range("dateType").Value = 3

    StartDate = Worksheet("TIME-PLAN.SIMP").Range("dateSimp")

Else: Worksheet("TIME-DATE PARAM").Range("dateType").Value = 4

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    Dim j As Integer
    j = 11

    StartDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl( _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(range ("Q13:Q820"), _
            Application.worksheetFunction.Match(Worksheet("TIME-PLAN.SIMP").range("dateLink").value), _
                                                Worksheet("TIME-PLAN.SIMP").range("A13:A820"), _
                                                i), _
                                                i), _
                                                Worksheet("TIME-PLAN.SIMP").range("dateSpacing").value, _
                                                j, _
                                                Worksheet("TIME-PLAN.SIMP").range("H2:L4"))

End If

End Function
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: At first glance I'd say you miss an `s` in `Worksheet`. Anbd second hint: You have a lot of `else` in your code.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned exactly which line ws giving you the error. *It's not working* isn't nearly as useful as the specific line location would be.

Comment: The first line that will give an error is the line `If Worksheet("TIME-DATE PARAM").Range("dateType").Value = 1 Then`  because OP missed an `s`. Then the several `Else` lines will fail. And the line `startdate =Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(  ...` is totally messed up.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answers, @Storax when you say I missed an S you mean WorksheetS instead of Worksheet ? Why several "else" will fail ?

Comment: I suggest to have a look at the syntax first: [Worksheet](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/) and [If condition](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-if/).

Comment: Ok so I have switch from "else" to "elseif... then" and put the missing "S". Now I'm quite sure the big mistake is the line you discribed as "messed up". I have replace the whole "messed up lines" with StarteDate ="case4" and it's working fine. I'm trying to use the classic excel functions (worday.intl combined with Index and match). Do you know if there is a way for StartDate to return a formula like this one =WORKDAY.INTL(INDEX(a fixed range of cells;MATCH(dateLink;same range of fixed cells;0);0);dateSpacing;11;Holidays)

Comment: I am afraid, I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Insert at the top:

```
Option Explicit
```

Since all your inputs are `Range` objects, replace all lines like:

```
Worksheet("TIME-DATE PARAM").Range("dateType").Value = 2
```

with:

```
dateType.Value = 2
```

This is because the `Range` object already "knows" its Parent worksheet.

Also replace:

```
WorkDay_Intl
```

with:

```
WorkDay.Intl
```

*There may be other errors.*